# What CSS rule do I need to hide "tr" elements whose children "td"'s have child "input" elements with empty value attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I realize the question title is a bit confusing, but in reality, I mean to ask exactly what I've typed.

I am trying to write a CSS file for printing (nausea rising) and I am wanting to eliminate white space in unnecessary rows (the necessity, or rather, the lack thereof, is determined by input fields that have empty values).

The proper CSS syntax (if there exists any) is relentlessly eluding me.

I have used selectors like this before:

```
input[type=text]
```

So I could assume (hopefully... gulp!) that I could use something like:

```
input[val='']
```

However:

1) I'm not sure using apostrophes/quotes is even legal inside those brackets (what's that area of a CSS selector called, again?)

2) I wouldn't know how to put a selector inside those brackets (if even possible) since the actual "tr"s are what I'm trying to target, just "tr"s with td children with input children with empty vals.

Wallowing in random syntax, I tried:

```
tr[td input val=]
```

Very much NOT to my surprise, did I find that obviously this didn't work, then I realized I had no clue how to proceed, if I wanted to accomplish this strictly in CSS.

~ *Takes a quick breathe*

Okay, I realize I'm asking a lot out of CSS, but if it's selector system wasn't so powerful I wouldn't even assume this possible.

Lastly, I am already implementing javascript, jQuery, and even server-side C#.net (WebMatrix) so if this answer is best solved using these other languages, I don't mind, I just want the simplest cleanest solution, if possible, as any scripting method I use will require the addition of another class to all td elements therein, and there are many, not to mention the scripting itself.

Any help, as always, is greatly appreciated.

---------------------EDIT REGARDING ALNITAK'S ANSWER------------------------

I tried to add the following jQuery just before my `window.print();` JavaScript command:

```
$('tr > td > input[value=""]').parent().parent().css('display', 'none');
$('tr > td > input[value=""]').parent().parent().css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

I have checked my # of parents, and all is as it should be there. The only other thing that might be interfering is that I have razor embedded in the values by default (although they are explicitly assigned empty strings on page start so, it should be fine). Just in case though I also tried:

```
$('tr > td > input[value=null]').parent().parent().css('display', 'none');
$('tr > td > input[value=null]').parent().parent().css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

But, alas, to no avail.

Comment: Thanks for all the quick replies, guys! It will take me a while to investigate the solutions, but I WILL accept the answer that works best, and will upvote any other useful answers, Thanks, again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with pure selectors, because the end result of a selector is always the matching child node, not their ancestors.

You need to find those matching child nodes, and then climb back up the tree again, e.g. in jQuery:

```
$('tr > td > input[value=""]').parent().parent().css('color', 'red');
```

You can use `.closest('tr')` instead of `.parent().parent()` if you prefer.

Also using jQuery, you can use the `.has()` function to create a chain that matches elements containing particular children:

```
$('tr').has('> td > input[value=""]').css('color', 'red');
```

The `.has()` function is more efficient than using the `:has` pseudo-selector, although I would expect neither to be as efficient as the full selector above which takes advantage of `document.querySelectorAll` on modern browsers.

If you can't get the `input[value=""]` part to work, try this:

```
$('tr > td > input').filter(function() {
    return this.value == '';
})....
```

Comment: I noticed that your answers are in jQuery. It is necessary to do it through scripting (not that I mind, it is a one-liner, after all)?

Comment: @VoidKing yes, you have to use scripting - per the first line of my answer, you can't do this in pure CSS.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but which would be faster, `.closest('tr')` or `.parent().parent()`  If it is insanely negligible, I apologize. I add new code I discover to my "mental-toolbox", if you will, and just don't want to develop any bad habits.

Comment: @VoidKing If I had to guess (I don't know for 100% certain) I would expect `.parent().parent()` to be faster, as it just takes the `.parentNode` property and doesn't have to test what type of node the parent actually is.

Comment: Thanks! One more question (I think...): After I am done hiding these `tr`s, is reshowing them (using the same code, more or less) after the `window.print();` javascript function viable, or will it hang up, as it waits for the user (printing also acts a bit different from browser to browser and I need this to be compatible with IE8 and up)

Comment: I couldn't get your solution to work, yet. Please look at my OP edit to see why I think it might not.

Comment: Okay, that did the trick, although I wonder why your original solution did not. IMPORTANT: Is there a way to do the same thing we've been doing, but only if ALL child input's values = ""?

Comment: @VoidKing I suspect the original didn't work because the `[]` selector looks at the _attribute_ value, and not the current _property_ value.  To solve your updated problem, consider looking for the rows where _any_ value is non-empty, and then invert the set.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly :

You can't do what you want to in CSS, not yet anyway.

What you're looking for is a css parent selector.

http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/

By using the selector:

```
tr td input[value='']
```

You'll be selecting the inputs, not the <tr>s.

One way to achieve what you want is to have something "watch" the page you're on (from javascript) and apply a class to anything you want hidden, when you print. Then in your print stylesheet just use that class to hide!

Comment: I must admit, your second approach is rather snazzy, Sir! That may be a really quick and easy approach, too!

Comment: using `addClass` won't force the elements to lose any other classes will it?

Answer (score 1):

Your prose translates to this CSS:

```
!tr>td>input:matches(:not([value]),[value=''])
```

However, both `!` and `:matches` are [CSS4 selectors](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/) that are not implemented yet. You'd be better off using JavaScript:

```
var qsa = document.querySelectorAll("tr>td>input"), l=qsa.length, i;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    if( qsa[i].value == '') qsa[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the :has() selector: http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

Description: Selects elements which contain at least one element that matches the specified selector.

```
$('tr:has(td input[value=""])').css({color:'red'});
```

Comment: dunno why this was downvoted... at least give a reason, or undo it please.

Comment: I was actually wondering the same thing, although haven't tried it yet. Too many answers :)

Comment: this'll work, but it won't be fast as `:has` is a jQuery pseudo-selector, not real CSS.

Comment: @Alnitak But aren't all the answers here using jQuery? What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Alnitak Just curious why (if) I shouldn't go down this road.

Comment: There's no way to do what you want using JUST CSS unfortunately.

Comment: @VoidKing sure, I was just pointing out that it's not optimal - using `.has()` is better than `:has`.

Comment: @Alnitak can you show some kind of benchmark for that claim? In either case, the solution would work.

Comment: @Alnitak No offense, but while this may not be the best solution, I don't think it deserves a downvote, imho.

Comment: @VoidKing I didn't give it one